# how to clean a JSON file and store it to another file in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read a JSON file with Python. This file is described by the authors as not strict JSON. In order to convert it to strict JSON, they suggest this approach:

```
import json

def parse(path):
    g = gzip.open(path, 'r')
    for l in g:
        yield json.dumps(eval(l))
```

however, not being familiar with Python, I am able to execute the script but I am not able to produce any output file with the new clean JSON. How should I modify the script in order to produce a new JSON file? I have tried this:

```
import json

class Amazon():

    def parse(self, inpath, outpath):
        g = open(inpath, 'r')
        out = open(outpath, 'w')
        for l in g:
            yield json.dumps(eval(l), out)

amazon = Amazon()
amazon.parse("original.json", "cleaned.json")
```

but the output is an empty file. Any help more than welcome

Comment: Assuming that `json.dumps(eval(l))` returns a string, change `yield json.dumps(eval(l), out)` to `out.write(json.dumps(eval(l)))`.  Make sure you really really really trust your input.  With `eval` you are running arbitrary data as code.  See [Is Using eval In Python A Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

class Amazon():

    def parse(self, inpath, outpath):
        g = open(inpath, 'r')
        with open(outpath, 'w') as fout:
            for l in g:
                fout.write(json.dumps(eval(l)))

amazon = Amazon()
amazon.parse("original.json", "cleaned.json")
```

Comment: fout.write(json.dumps(eval(l)) should be fout.write(json.dumps(eval(l))) I think

Answer (score 1):

another shorter way of doing this

```
import json

class Amazon():
    def parse(readpath, writepath):
        with open(readpath) as g, open(writepath, 'w') as fout:
            for l in g:
                json.dump(eval(l), fout)

amazon = Amazon()
amazon.parse("original.json", "cleaned.json")
```

While handling json data it is better to use json modules json.dump(json, output_file) for dumping json in file and json.load(file_path) to load the data. In this way you can get maintain json wile saving and reading json data.

For very large amount of data say 1k+ use python pandas module.

Comment: thanks, yes a shorter way but that class is going to grow so I prefer that approach... you should change writefile to writepath

Comment: Well, I was talking about the content of function. You can insert this function in your class. I would suggest you to use this function because it help you to get get json data when you read the file again.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I am so newbie to Python that I don't really understand your point... on a minor note, I think you have to change open(writefile, 'w') to open(writepath, 'w')